# Prevent form submission after submit button has been clicked using cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that submits values to back-end, but I wish to have a cancel button that stops the submission of the form.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadForm">
/*
*
parameters
*
*/
<button type="submit" value="submit" id="SubmitButton">Submit</button>
<button type="button" value="cancel" id="CancelButton">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone please tell how it can be done?

Comment: use `event.preventDefult();` So many time asked.

Comment: @Parth Trivedi...I doubt if event.preventDefault is gonna work in this case.Once the submit button is clicked,the form will be posted,how will preventdefault stop it in midway??

Comment: You can have a `click` handler and depending on condition, you can `return false` and it should stop.

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752020/jquery-file-upload-cancel-uploading-by-javascript

Comment: If you mean stop the request while it's processed you could use 'abort' method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort()

Comment: @LGSon OP isn't using any XHR request here

Comment: @darcy, at what point do you need that cancel button that should stop the submit?

Comment: @LGSon i need the cancel button after the submit button has been clicked, it given an option to the user to stop the submission of form after he has clicked on submit button

Comment: @darcy Okay, how long time does the client side action last after the submit button been clicked ? ... I mean the "onsubmit" action that obviously does some heavy work.

Comment: @LGSon it depends on upload.php script, i have images and some basic input values that wil b saved in db

Answer (score 4):

Solution that **could** work:

```
var cancelObject = '';

$('#UploadForm').on('submit', function(e){

   //prevent default submit
   e.preventDefault();

   //submit via ajax
   cancelObject = $.post('upload.php', $( "#UploadForm" ).serialize());

});

$('#cancel_button').click(function(){

   //Cancel the request
   cancelObject.abort();

});
```

**UNTESTET! - Only an idea that could work....**

Comment: tried ur code, it has stopped the submission of form even on submit button

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Here's your HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadForm">
  <button type="submit" value="submit" id="SubmitButton">Submit</button>
  <button type="button" id="CancelButton" disabled>Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Here's your jQuery and JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  var $form = $('#UploadForm');
  var form = $form.get(0);
  var $submit = $('#SubmitButton');
  var $cancel = $('#CancelButton');
  var xhr = null;

  function cleanup() {
    xhr = null;
    $submit.removeAttr('disabled');
    $cancel.attr('disabled', true);
  }

  function doneCallback() {
    // your code for completed form submission goes here
    // redirect the page or whatever you need to do
    cleanup();
  }

  $cancel.on('click', function() {
    if($cancel.attr('disabled')) {
      return;
    }

    if(xhr instanceof XMLHttpRequest) {
      xhr.abort();
    }

    cleanup();
  })

  $form.on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open($form.attr('method'), $form.attr('action'), true);
    xhr.addEventListener('load', doneCallback);

    $submit.attr('disabled', true);
    $cancel.removeAttr('disabled');

    xhr.send(new FormData(form));

    return false;
  });
});
```

This uses the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) API so check your [browser support for that](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2).

Comment: i tried ur code, although it is showing in console that my upload.php has been aborted, but the script is running and values are getting saved in db

Comment: @darcy Probably because the request is happening in milliseconds. Can you add an artificial throttle either on the client or server? Make it last several seconds. This is the reason you don't often see "Cancel" buttons next to "Submit" buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Add `onsubmit` attribute to the button tag:
`<button type="submit" value="submit" id="SubmitButton" onsubmit="return cancel()"> SubmitIt </button>`

```
Javascript:
function cancel()
{
    var decision=null;

     alert("Press Y to submit or N to cancel");
      decision=prompt("Do you want to submit?","Y or N");
      if( decision.equals("Y"))
{
      return true;
      alert("Form has been submitted");

} 
     else if (decision.equals("N"))
{
    return false;
    alert("Form submission has been cancelled");

}
     else
{
    alert("wrong input.Re-submit the form.");
     return false;

}

}
```

Form will be submitted if the value returned is `true`.The js function asks the user if he wants to proceed and submit or cancel the action.

Comment: i don't want the option of asking the user, i removed this part and tried but it didnt work

Comment: It wouldn't work without user input!..It depends on the value of variable decision.So,if you don't take user input,form submission will get cancelled everytime.

Comment: This doesn't create a button.If you want a button,use Chris's solution.My solution could be used to ask user and take an input but a button is always better.

Comment: i tried Chris sol, but the issue in it is that it has completely stopped the form submission, even if i click d submit button it is not submitting the form, i want that user clicks on submit button and after dat if he wishes to stop the script, the cancel button should stop the form submission

Answer (score -1):

This is not as simple as just abort the submit. As soon as that button is clicked there is no practical way to know how much, if any, of its data has been sent yet.

A web browser and a web server doesn't keep its connection between the requests and therefore stopping a script client side doesn't mean it stops it server side.

To abort that submit, you need to send a second request to the server telling so, then at the server, it might already been saved so a delete will be required, and if so, you will then need some unique id to both identify the submit and its abort request, as they will arrive server side as 2 unique requests.

At the server, setting some rules of what and how much data is required to actually save it to the db could be done, still, what if one user has only 1 image and a second has 3, how to know when it is supposed to be an "aborted submit" or not, based on such rules?

A time delay before saving it might be something else, when an abort can be accepted, but again, very difficult to make fail safe and will need the unique id's anyway to identify the requests.

I guess your best bet is to save it, as I would like to believe most user want that, and if a second request comes within a certain time frame, it allows to be deleted.

Accept and use [Patrick Roberts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34347937/2827823) as a start would be a good idea.

At these 2 similar post you might find additional help.

- [onSubmit returning false is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543963/onsubmit-returning-false-is-not-working)
- [Onsubmit still submits when returning false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086692/onsubmit-still-submits-when-returning-false)

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, won't this work for you?

```
form (...) onsubmit="return false;"
```

In place of 'return false' you can use any JS function you wish. Typical use for this is form validation, for example.